# Ffmpeg - Segmenting A Continuous Live Stream Into One Minute Stand Alone Files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to capture an RTSP stream from an IP camera 24 hours a day and save it in one minute long files.   So far by reading the documentation I have managed to be partially successful.  I am capturing the stream and the files all have one minute of video.  The problem is the first file generated has one minute of video and all is fine.   The second file generated indicates the captured video is two minutes long but during first minute the screen is blank and there is only a minute of video at the end.   The third file is the same except there are two minutes of blank screen before the actual one minute of captured video at the end.   I would bet the 60th file would have 59 minutes of blank screen and one minute of captured video.

What I would like is a stand alone file for each minute, but I cannot seem to find the switch to add on the command line to do this.  Any ideas?  Thanks

EDIT

Current command line:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -r 25 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -reorder_queue_size 8000 -max_delay 10000000 -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_format avi "/vidcam2cont/ffmpeg_capture-%03d.avi"`

There are probably things that could be removed or changed but it took me forever reading the documentation and a lot of posts with considerable experimentation to stop all the dropped frames.  This particular conglomeration produces good video.  If it segmented the stream correctly, I would be very happy..

Comment: What does your command look like now?

Answer (score 1):

For segmenting to AVI, you should reset timestamps.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -reorder_queue_size 8000 -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -r 25 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_format avi "/vidcam2cont/ffmpeg_capture-%03d.avi"`

Comment: This results in std_out messages (~35 per second - numbers increment each time) as follows     `[segment @ 0xff9e60] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 353, current: 295; changing to 354. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.`

Comment: The output files seem the same except the additional time added to each new file is now about 10 seconds instead of 60, i.e.,  file2 10 seconds blank 60 seconds video, file2 20 seconds blank 60 seconds video, etc.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I ran the command with the -report option and a log file was created.   Even editing out the similar lines that repeat, it is 182 lines long and if they wrap when posted it would be more.  Based on the character limit for comments, I imagine I would have use an "Answer" area.  Is that going to be an appropriate thing to do since it is not an answer to the original problem?    I don't want to upset any moderators.

Comment: Normally. you would upload it to a service like Pastebin and share a link here.

Comment: Here it is.  I hope it helps.      https://pastebin.com/aUtK6hYW

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the log file was not much help so I kept trying different things and found the following solved the problem of the ever increasing lengthening of the black/blank screen period before the one minute of video.  Again there are probably things that are not quite right or not needed, but so far it seems to work.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -reorder_queue_size 8000 -vsync drop -i rtsp://192.168.10.203:554/11 -map 0 -r 30 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/path/%d-%m-%Y__%H_%M_test.avi"`